# Rails s3_direct_upload how to disable it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, asset-pipeline

In Rails, I am using `s3_direct_upload` gem for asset(doc file) upload. Right now if I try to upload an image file as a different asset, it is directly uploading to s3. I need to disable this option for image upload and it should be enable only for document upload.

Answer (score 0):

`s3_direct_upload` is provides form helper methods to upload images to s3 directly. like this `s3_uploader_form`. It just reduces your [jquery_file_upload](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) and s3 configuration.

But you can still upload image to your local file system. Using simple `form_tag`. i.e. When you want to upload images to s3 use `s3_uploader_form` syntax and when you want to upload images to local file system then use simple `form_tag` or any other rails provided form syntax.

For uploading images using ajax use `remotipart` gem with simple form syntax.

Comment: Thank You. I will check it once again.